# Is there a sharp phase change on error rate near the error correction threshold?

Tags: probabilistic-circuits

My rough intuition is that if we want to efficiently compute using noisy gates, the probability of success will exhibit threshold behavior as we cross the error correction threshold.  Here is an attempt at formalizing this intuition.  The setting is different from the usual classical/quantum threshold theorems, as the circuit sizes are fixed.

Let $d$ be the number of Boolean inputs, $n \gg d$ be the size of circuit we want to simulate, and $m \gg n$ the number of gates we have available.  Assume we have some complete family of Boolean gates with error probability $p \ll 1$, where $p$ will vary.  Let $F_{p,k}$ be the set of distributions on Boolean functions realizable with error $p$, size $k$ circuits.  Define the minimax success probability

$$q_{p,n,m} = \min_{f \in F_{0,n}} \max_{g \in F_{p,m}} \min_{x \in \{0,1\}^d} \Pr(f(x) = g(x))$$

That is, our adversary picks a size $n$ deterministic circuit to simulate, we pick a size $m$ noisy circuit to approximate it, and our adversary chooses an input.

For fixed $n, m$, what does the function $q_{p,n,m}$ look like?  Does it have sharp threshold behavior?  I primarily care about classical circuits, but am also interested if there are results for quantum circuits.

Comment: I moved this to mathoverflow, since it isn't getting any notice here after four days: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466844/is-there-a-sharp-phase-change-on-circuit-error-rate-near-the-error-correction-th.